# Validate a file when creating content in Alfresco

Tags: forms, validation, alfresco

I want to upload some XML files to Alfresco, so the create con tent form has an input file form element.

I need to check if the XML is well-formed, and I already have the backend validation functions triggered on ResourceBehavior.onContentUpdate. If the XML is malformed, I want to notify the user with a dialog window.

So far, I can prevent the user to submit malformed XML by throwing an exception when the XML is malformed, but I can't figure out how to have share to display an error message.

I have been looking at all the validation JS in share, but remember, file input forms need to be submitted first so that you can have a look at its content, thus the validation has to be server-sided.

Any pointers on where should I begin?

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are going to have is that your backend behaviour is not aware of the specific client session that made the changes and what client session it is that needs to be notified.

If you want to display a useful message then you are going to have to write some additional Share customisation. Some options which you can explore are having an action or webscript that returns whether the XML is valid or not and customising the Share upload form to execute this action/webscript after the file has been uploaded and then return the relevant message to the user.

You'll find a pretty detailed post on modifying the upload form here:
http://www.ixxus.com/blog/2011/09/customising-upload-files-dialog-alfresco-share

If you're feeling lazy then I'd consider just aborting the file creation if the XML is invalid during an onCreate behaviour and then the user will see an 'Internal Error'.